# Changing i breaks the code

Tags: jquery

So I created a simple JQuery program that puts form elements in a table and creates a select item and adds an option for the number of rows each time a new row is added:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var i=1;
        $("#kopche").click(function(){
            var name=$("#name");
            var index=$("#indeks");
            var grade=$("#grade");

            alert("Grade");

            var body=$("#body");
            body.append("<tr><td>"+name.val()+"</td><td>"+index.val()+"</td><td>"+grade.val()+"</td></tr>");

            name.val("");
            index.val("");
            grade.val("5");
            if(i==1)
            {
                $("table").after('<br/><br/><select id="brojka"></select>');
                var br=$("#brojka");
            }
            br.append('<option>'+i+'</option>');

            i=i+1;

            alert("Okey");
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
Name: <input type="text" id="name"/><br/><br/>
Index: <input type="text" id="indeks"/><br/><br/>
Grade: <select id="grade">
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select> <br/><br/>

<button id="kopche">Add</button>
<br/><br/>

<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td> <td>Index</td> <td>Grade</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="body">

</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

However the program isn't running well. There seems to be a problem when in the line i=i+1.

Any ideas?

Comment: Need to be  lot more specifc than *"isn't running well"* which is meaningless. Take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the `br` variable if `i` isn't 1.

Here's the fix.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var i=1;
        $("#kopche").click(function(){
            var name=$("#name");
            var index=$("#indeks");
            var grade=$("#grade");

            alert("Grade");

            var body=$("#body");
            body.append("<tr><td>"+name.val()+"</td><td>"+index.val()+"</td><td>"+grade.val()+"</td></tr>");

            name.val("");
            index.val("");
            grade.val("5");
            if(i==1)
            {
                $("table").after('<br/><br/><select id="brojka"></select>');
            }
            var br=$("#brojka");
            br.append('<option>'+i+'</option>');

            i=i+1;

            alert("Okey");
        });
    });
```

Hope this helps.